# How do import .csv files in VS Code using SQL, and analyse the data?

Tags: sql, sqlite, csv, visual-studio-code, import-csv

I've got the two csv tables below.

Users:

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Bradley |
| 2 | Peter |
| 3 | Sanjay |

Purchases:

| id | date | user_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-11-01 | 2 |
| 2 | 2023-10-03 | 3 |
| 3 | 2023-04-21 | NULL |

I have them saved as csv files on VS Code. I want to write the below code for the two tables above.

```
select * from users where id not in (select user_id from purchases)
```

The SQL code sits in a .sql file on VS Code. When I run that code in a new file I get the below error message.

**Code language not supported or defined.**

How do I read in the csv files, which sit on my GDrive ("G:\My Drive\Visual Studio Code\<file_name>.csv"), into the SQL code and how can I get the code language supported?

I have SQLite extension (alexcvzz.vscode-sqlite) installed on VS Code and it is enabled globally.

I don't understand what the problem is.
[image]

Comment: why do you think an EDITOR can do SQL stuff

Comment: write a script that read the CSV and fills the sqlite tables, then use an SQL CLI program to perform the query or do it from the same script

Comment: The sqlite3 command line tool can import csv files into sqlite tables; see https://sqlite.org/cli.html#importing_files_as_csv_or_other_formats . I'm sure there's some way to script that process in vscode.